# What does RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode do

Tags: c#, .net, clr, base-class-library

The `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(object)` method allows generating hash codes based on the identity of an object. MSDN [states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11tbk3h9.aspx):

> The RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode method always calls the
>   Object.GetHashCode method non-virtually, even if the object's type has
>   overridden the Object.GetHashCode method.

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
[SecuritySafeCritical]
public static extern int GetHashCode(object o);
```

However, when inspecting the `Object.GetHashCode()` method using Reflector (.NET 4.0), we'll see the following code:

```
public virtual int GetHashCode()
{
    return RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(this);
}
```

This makes me believe that the MSDN documentation is wrong, since calling `Object.GetHashCode` from within the `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(object)` would cause a stack overflow.

So what is the actual behavior of `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(object)` and how does it work? How does it calculate the hash?

Comment: @dtb there are some places where C# makes a non-virtual call to a virtual method - `base.*` for example. In most scenarios, using `call` on a virtual method will make the CLI shout loudly at you - it isn't allowed, *regardless* of the language of the caller.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think the MSDN documentation is trying to describe the **behaviour**, not the implementation. The key point: `RuntimeHelpers` returns the **default** implementation that you would get were `object.GetHashCode()` *not* overridden.

This is really useful if, for example, you want to build a *reference equality* lookup, even for types that have overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. I do this in a serializer that I maintain, using `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode()` and `Object.ReferenceEquals`.

Comment: So, the documentation is a bit misleading, or am I just interpretering it incorrectly?

Comment: @Steven yes, saying that it "calls the Object.GetHashCode method non-virtually" is a bit misleading, especially given the two other implementations shown here (in your post, and "Me.Name"'s post)

Comment: @Jon *yes*, but based on the two reflector dumps in this post and one of the answers, it isn't actually how the IL is implemented.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Yes, and I'm going to elaborate on that in my answer instead of in comments :)

Comment: @Jon I shall look forward to it ;p

Comment: "you want to build a reference equality lookup". And guess what, that's what I'm trying to do ;-)

Comment: I guess there is a typo. It should be RuntimeHelpers instead of RuntimeTypeHelpers

Answer (score 14):

The point is that `object.GetHashCode()` can be overridden - and frequently is, e.g. by `string`. That means you can't find out the "identity hash code" which the *default* implementation of `object.GetHashCode()` returns.

This can be useful if you want to implement an equalty comparer (e.g. for a `HashSet`) which *only* considers object identity.

For example:

```
public class IdentityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T : class
{
    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        // Just for clarity...
        return object.ReferenceEquals(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T x)
    {
        // The nullity check may be unnecessary due to a similar check in
        // RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode, but it's not documented
        return x == null ? 0 : RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(x);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
string x = "hello";
string y = new StringBuilder("h").Append("ello").ToString();
Console.WriteLine(x == y); // True (overloaded ==)
Console.WriteLine(x.GetHashCode() == y.GetHashCode()); // True (overridden)

IdentityComparer<string> comparer = new IdentityComparer<string>();
Console.WriteLine(comparer.Equals(x, y)); // False - not identity

// Very probably false; not absolutely guaranteed (as ever, collisions
// are possible)
Console.WriteLine(comparer.GetHashCode(x) == comparer.GetHashCode(y));
```

EDIT: Just to clarify a bit...

> So what is the actual behavior of RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(object) and how does it work?

The *observed* behaviour is that the value returned from `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(object)` is the same as the value which would be returned from a non-virtual call to `Object.GetHashCode()`. (You can't write that non-virtual call in C# easily.)

As for how it *works* - that's an implementation detail :) It doesn't really matter IMO which way round things occur (what calls what). The important thing is the documented behaviour, which is correct. Heck, different versions of mscorlib could implement this differently - it wouldn't matter at all from a user's point of view. Without decompilation, you shouldn't be able to tell the difference.

It would (IMO) have been far more confusing for `Object.GetHashCode` to have been documented in terms of `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode()`.

Comment: RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode handles null, so there is no need to do it explicitly.

Comment: @MattSmith: Hmm... unfortunately that's not documented as far as I can see, so I wouldn't want to rely on it - but I'll add a comment.

Comment: Good point.  I actually considered it "documented" since normally Microsoft's documentation includes a clause in the documentation when it does throw (for example: System.ArgumentNullException: o is null.).  But perhaps they are not always diligent.

Comment: @MattSmith in fact `object.GetHashCode()` handles null returning 0 too, if you're using a language that lets you non-virtually call an instance method on a null instance. (AFAIK, for all implementations out there). Of course, C# isn't such a language.

Answer (score 4):

Strange, when I look at System.Object.GetHashCode via Reflector I see

```
public virtual int GetHashCode()
{
    return InternalGetHashCode(this);
}
```

and for runtimehelper:

```
public static int GetHashCode(object o)
{
    return object.InternalGetHashCode(o);
}
```

Perhaps it's a framework difference? I'm looking at 2.0 assemblies.

Comment: Don't remove this answer. It shows that the implementation can vary, but the behavior is still as specified. (Your answer was mentioned in Skeet's answer).

Answer (score 0):

From your own question, it looks like `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(Object)` is really the implementation of the non-overridden `Object.GetHashCode()`.